# Where in my Javascript do I add setTimeout to make it work?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am a newbie and have implemented this bit of Javascript that I got elsewhere and it works beautifully, getting my div to scroll with the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- // sick
var scroll = 0;
var marginTop = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        $("#scrollregister").animate({
            "marginTop": marginTop + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false
        });
    });
});
// -->
</script>
```

My problem is that I'd like to delay the execution of this script (not just increase the number of seconds it takes to execute, but delay the time when it starts). I understand I can use setTimeout to do this, and I've both googled and searched this site to see if I could figure out by looking at other code using setTimeout how to add setTimeout to the above code. However, despite my best trial and error, I fail to implement it correctly. I hope you will be so kind as to tell me how to implement it.

Comment: simply increase the duration:3000, it make this animation duration to  3 seconds.

Comment: @v.ArunKumar : "(not just increase the number of seconds it takes to execute, but delay the time when it starts)"

Comment: duration:3000 means animation happen for 3 seconds. its not a delay to start the animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var scroll = 0;
var marginTop = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        window.setTimeout(scrollDiv, 2000);        
    });
    function scrollDiv()
    {
        $("#scrollregister").animate({
            "marginTop": marginTop + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: false
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, harsha, that works beautifully! How wonderful it is to receive help like this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @EvaG. : Glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Delay start by 3 seconds and execution duration of 4 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- // sick
var scroll = 0;
var marginTop = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        $("#scrollregister").animate({
            "marginTop": marginTop + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            queue: false
        });
    },3000);
})}
);
// -->
</script>
```